# Force PowerShell Execution in a Build Task

Tags: azure-devops, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have a build configure in Visual Studio Team Services that was working well up until today when it inexplicably started using the Node execution steps instead of the PowerShell ones.  The build agent is running on a Windows machine so based on my knowledge, it should not be using the Node route.

Can anyone provide insight into this?  One of the tasks specifically is the NPM and NPM Install tasks.

The first line normally is:

```
2015-11-30T17:57:28.3209069Z Executing the powershell script: C:\agent-internal\tasks\NpmInstall\0.1.3\NpmInstall.ps1
```

And it has switched to:

```
2015-11-30T19:36:08.2543618Z Set workingFolder to default: C:\agent-internal\tasks\Npm\0.2.0
```

This is causing a rippled error effect.  Any ideas?  If I could just force PowerShell script execution, I think I'd be good.

Comment: Do you use the hosted agent or your own agent? I just tested a build configuration and in my case it still runs the PowerShell script for the npm task (also at version 0.2.0).

Comment: You could also try to add an issue at the [vso-agent-tasks](https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent-tasks/issues) repository. Someone there should be able to help you.

Comment: It's my own agent.  No reason that I can see for it to think it's running a cross-platform agent.  I'll try the vso-agent-tasks repo.

Comment: I just restarted our build agent service and after updating the agent to 1.91.1 its now also running the node script instead of the PowerShell script, but still without an error. What error message did you get?

Answer (score 2):

In short: The Node handler can run on Windows just fine. The task was updated to be cross-platform compatible.

Each build task can ship with multiple implementations of the same task. There are a number of handlers:

- powershell - The now deprecated (as of agent 2.0) powershell handler that uses runs the powershell script inside a special powershell host.
- powershell3 - The new powershell handler that uses a special module to interact with the agent which allows the scripts to also run outside of the agent (handy for debugging)
- javascript - The now deprecated cross platform handler that runs javascript inside node
- node - The new javascript handler that uses the vsts-node-lib to communicate to the agent in much the same way as the powershell3 handler does. This in either Node 5 or Node 6 LTS.

  - node10 - the same base infrastructure as the node handler, but this runs in the node 10 version that ships alongside the agent since Nov 2018.

The Execution Section in the task.json defines which implementation is run. The agent on Windows supports powershell, powershell3 and node, it favors the Node runner, then powershell3 and then powershell, unless [there is a specific "platforms" section that gives precedence to a specific handler](https://github.com/jessehouwing/vsts-variable-tasks/blob/master/vsts-variable-expand/task.json#L33-L46).

When the build agent updates itself and when new versions of tasks are published to the Marketplace of VSTS, the task author can opt to include a node implementation, making the task cross-platform. Most task authors will prefer to then use that one implementation on all platforms to ensure feature parity and to prevent issues that only show up when a specific handler is invoked. For backwards compat reasons Task Authors tend to also ship the old implementation. In my own case I've started to log a build warning when the old implementation is being used.